# Facebook : login lntegration in my website

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

After the successful login of Facebook, I am getting the error:

> Invalid Scopes: user_checkins. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

My code is,

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
    Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
    <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.your-domain.com/your-page.html" />
    <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title"         content="Your Website Title" />
    <meta property="og:description"   content="Your description" />
    <meta property="og:image"         content="http://www.your-domain.com/path/image.jpg" />

  <title>AngularQuickstart</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<script  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng2-bootstrap/1.1.16/ng2-bootstrap.umd.min.js" > </script>
<link rel="" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css" />
<link rel="" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css.map" />
<link rel="" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-grid.css.map" />

<!-- <script src="fb-sdk.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>

 <script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
      //FB.logout();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  }

  function facebookLogin() {
        FB.login(function(response) {

            statusChangeCallback(response);

             if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Authenticated!');
                // location.reload(); //or do whatever you want
            } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
            }
        },
        {
            scope: 'email,user_checkins'
        });
    } 

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

      //alert('test');
  FB.init({

    appId : 'XXX',

    channelURL : '', // Channel File, not required so leave empty
    status     : true,
    oauth      : true, 

    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
  });


  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log("***** FB login response");
        console.log(response);
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="facebookLogin();" value="fblogin" />

<div id="status">
</div> 



</body>
</html>
```

Yesterday it was worked for me. I can get the response after the successful login. But today I am getting the error. Thanks.

Comment: that permission was deprecated a long time ago. not sure why it worked yesterday, but it does not exist anymore. you don´t use it in your code anyway.

Comment: @luschn Thanks for the comment. But I copied and altered the code from facebook api only... If it will work means , How can I make it work to achieve the same functionality ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve, and where did you copy the code from?

Comment: @Luschn I need to integrate the facebook login feature in my website. So that the user of my site need not to register in my site... So to enable this feature, If user clicks the FB login button in my site, it has to show a pop-up of Facebook login screen and i need a callback response from Facebook to know the user status and his details. So that I get a personalized view for him.

Comment: then why are you trying to use a permission that has been removed a long time ago? what for do you want to use user_checkins?

Comment: I don't know how to use it. Can u please help me to resolve it ? Also i dont know , where I used that user_checkins. I am just a learner.

Comment: just remove the permission then

Comment: Thanks for Ur reply.... I don't know where to remove permission s and edit the code. Could u please do it and post it as an answer ?

Comment: search for "user_checkins". i can´t make it any more detailed for you.

Comment: I searched. But there is no word like 'user_checkins' in my code.

Comment: seriously? it´s right there... "scope: 'email,user_checkins'"

Comment: Oh no ! I feel really bad. Sorry @ Mr. luschn